# Validate an option array

Tags: settings-api, validation

We use the default WordPress `register_setting()` function to validate theme options.  This call, for example:

```
register_setting( 'options-group', 'option1', 'intval' );
```

Will validate whether or not `$option1` is an integer.

What can I use to pass an array of options to validate each member of the array?

For example:

```
$options = array(
    'options1' => 4,              // intval
    'options2' => '127.0.0.1',    // IP address
    'options3' => 'test@test.com' // Email address
);
```

Comment: Validating whether or not elements exist in an array isn't really a WordPress question ... it's basic PHP.

Comment: actually i write a simple example but with callback functions its wp specific question imo.. this is not normal validation question -.-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do is build your own data validation function.  Ozh wrote [a great tutorial](http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/05/handling-plugins-options-in-wordpress-28-with-register_setting/) about this earlier, but here's the gist of it ...

Assume your options array is called `$my_options` and it contains three fields, `'text'`, `'age'`, and `'isauthorized'`.

You would still register it the same way:

```
register_setting( 'my_setting', 'my_options', 'my_validation_function' );
```

But you see how we used a custom callback for the third parameter?  Now we just need to define that custom function:

```
function my_validation_function( $input ) {
    // Validate age as an integer
    $input['age'] = intval( $input['age'] );

    // Strip HTML tags from text to make it safe
    $input['text'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['text'] );

    // Make sure isauthorized is only true or false (0 or 1)
    $input['isauthorized'] = ( $input['isauthorized'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );

    return $input;
}
```

---

**Alternatively**

If you want to make your validation functions a bit more flexible, you can use WordPress' built-in filters to avoid having to repeat your code.  You still register your validation the same way:

```
register_setting( 'my_setting', 'my_options', 'my_validation_function' );
```

But instead of checking each element of your array inside the validation function, you iterate through the array and delegate to filters:

```
function my_validation_function( $input ) {
    foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {
        $input[$key] = apply_filters( 'my_validation_' . $key, $value );
    }

    return $input
}
```

Now you can hook in whatever validation logic you need:

```
add_filter( 'my_validation_age', 'validate_numeric' );
function validate_numeric( $numeric ) {
    return intval( $numeric );
}

add_filter( 'my_validation_text', 'validate_text' );
function validate_text( $text ) {
    return wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $text );
}

add_filter( 'my_validation_isauthorized', 'validate_bool' );
function validate_bool( $bool ) {
    return $bool == 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

If you don't add a filter for one of your options, then the value of the option will remain unchanged.  Filters are also the way you want to go with functions that *return* content, and you can add as many as you want ... or attach your filters to any fields.

Let's say you had two numeric fields in your array - `age` and `numberChildren`.  Instead of creating an extra validation function that can handle the `numberChildren` field, you just add it to the filter:

```
add_filter( 'my_validation_numberChildren', 'validate_numeric' );
```

Comment: I like this alternate approach, but how would you handle saving checkboxes? They are only POSTed if they are checked, so the `foreach` that loops over every result will not save an unchecked checkbox.

Comment: Guys, how is this validation? If an input is wrong *nothing* should be saved, the user should be presented with the wrong input and a helpful validation message. `add_settings_error()` is the man!

Comment: This is not validation but sanitization. However, WordPress has a large share of badly designed or named functions. This one is overloaded both with sanitization and validation. To not update option because of invalid values just return old value. It is also wise to add an usable error using add_settings_error().

Answer (score 1):

It seems "different function usage for each option in array"'s solution is not like in my dream but i think this should work:

```
register_setting( 'my_setting', 'my_options', 'my_validation_function' );

function my_validation_function( $input ) {
    foreach ($input as $option=>$value){
        do_action('my_validation_'.$option, $option, $value);
    }
    return $input;
}
```

and then i can use custom functions for each option validation like this:

```
add_action('my_validation_age', 'my_validation_function_for_age', 10, 2);
function my_validation_function_for_age($option, $value) {
    $input[$option] = intval( $value );
}

add_action('my_validation_text', 'my_validation_function_for_text', 10, 2);
function my_validation_function_for_text($option, $value) {
    $input[$option] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $value );
}

add_action('my_validation_isauthorized', 'my_validation_function_for_isauthorized', 10, 2);
function my_validation_function_for_isauthorized($option, $value) {
    $input[$option] = ( $value == 1 ? 1 : 0 );
}
```

Writing here for future visitors. Accepting EAMann's solution.

Comment: Instead of retaining 2 "correct" answers, I added much of your code as an alternative solution below mine. I also elected to use filters instead of actions since that's really what you should be using to filter content in this fashion.